# getting error during submission in Google Kick start

Tags: c++

I am vary new to google coding competition platform.
I was practicing some questions which comes in google kick Start 2020 Below is the question. When i try to submit my solution , the google compiler shows "test set skipped"...although when i perform the compilation in my id it shows the right output even the output after runing into google editorial i got the right output but after submitting the code ,i always get error as "test set skipped"...don't no why.

another thing is that what precautions should we have to take while submitting code into google compiler or related to the google coding competitions.

Q. Problem asked in google kick Start round D 2020

Isyana is given the number of visitors at her local theme park on N consecutive days. The number of visitors on the i-th day is Vi. A day is record breaking if it satisfies both of the following conditions:
The number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the number of visitors on each of the previous days.
Either it is the last day, or the number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the number of visitors on the following day.
Note that the very first day could be a record breaking day!

Please help Isyana find out the number of record breaking days.

```
4
8
1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0
6
4 8 15 16 23 42
9
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5
6
9 9 9 9 9 9

output: 
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 1
Case #3: 3
Case #4: 0
```

````
#include<ios>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;
void fun(int n,int v[100000],int t)
{
    int count=0;
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if( v[i]>v[i-1] && v[i]>v[i+1] && max<v[i])
        {
            count++;
            max=v[i];
        }
        
        if(i==0)
        {
            if(v[0]>v[1])
            { 
                count++;
                max=v[0];
            }
        }
         
    }
    cout<<"Case #"<<t<<": "<<count<<"\n";
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    int v[100000];
    int t,c;
    cin>>t;
    for(c=1;c<=t;c++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>v[j];
        }
        fun(n,v,c);
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You `for` loop starts from 0 and you access `i-1` element of array. The same issue for `i+1` and i == n-1 at the end of the loop.

Comment: i don't get what you are saying..but what i understand is that u trying to tell me that why i am using this v[i]>v[i-1] && v[i]>v[i+1]... this 2 condition i have use to compare the previous and the next element from the current element.

Comment: "i don't get what you are saying.." your loop iterates `i` for 0...n-1. When i == 0 you try to access `v[i-1]` ie `v[-1]` which leads to UB. For the last value when i == n-1 you try to access `v[i+1]` ie `v[n]` which has the same issue. I understand why you try to access them but you are doing that wrong way.

Comment: so,i should start i from 1 to n-1 ...ok but what about  1st and last value.

Comment: "so,i should start i from 1 to n-1 ..." incorrect. You need to work on your algo. Hint you do not have to compare to previous element - max is sufficient. You need to check following but with condition - if it is not the last element.

Comment: but this solution giving the right output.

Comment: also what is mean by test set skipped...because  the test set which is provided in the question works fine in editorial.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to google coding competition, I guess you might be new to coding competitions as well.

And one important thing in coding competitions is handling edge cases. Here you start your loop with `i=0` but later access `i-1` element and different online judges give different messages for errors like these depending on how they handle it.

Same issue of `i+1` element also.

Generally if a test case fail in google competitions, they don't use computing power to try your code to the other test cases and hence test cases are skipped.

NOTE: Getting the right result in one compiler doesn't mean the code is correct and error free. Remember this. As I told earlier, different online judges handle errors differently. Sometimes code is passed without errors but the result shown will be completely different from what shown by other compilers. It's not rare and happens a lot with bad programming practices.

So be sure of the edge cases and possible segmentation faults, uninitialized variables kinds of errors because the online judges don't show the error message.

This is a general recommendation to coding competitors as many face unexpected messages on online judges and post on here in a confused state.